# Is it possible to make automatic multiple citations with csquotes and biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, quoting, csquotes

I'm using `csquotes` package with `biblatex`. There is a number of citations that require multiple references, which can be introduced with the `\autocites` command --- e.g. second hand citations (“cited in“ ou “*apud*”).

However, `\blockcquote[<pre>][<post>]{<Ref>}{<citation>}` accepts only single citations. Is that right? have I missed something?

To revert this, I'm using a simple `\blockquote{...\autocites[pre1][post1]{ref1}[pre2][post2]{ref2}\relax}` (the `\relax` [or a line break] is being required sometimes). But this way, the `\autocite` command doesn't respect the global citation style, resulting in a more simplified citation.

By the way, i'm working with the `verbose-trad3` style.

Here's a compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% To add the contents of the .bib file in the .tex file
    \begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
        @book{test1,
            author = {John Doe},
            title = {Example book to be cited},
            address = {Nowhere},
            publisher = {Some Publisher},
            year = {1990},
        }
        @book{test2,
            author = {Jane Smith},
            title = {A book that cites the former},
            address = {Somewhere},
            publisher = {A Publishing House},
            year = {2010},
        }
            @book{test1a,
                author = {Jane Deo},
                title = {Title for a first test},
                address = {Location},
                publisher = {Publisher 1},
                year = {2010},
            }
            @book{test2a,
                author = {John Sthim},
                title = {Title for a first test to cite another one},
                address = {Address},
                publisher = {Publisher 2},
                year = {2010},
            }
    \end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\usepackage{csquotes}
    \SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
    \SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}
\newcommand{\loremipsum}{%  I did this because using the lipsum package, the reference appeared in a new line
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus ante at urna tempor iaculis. Donec et mi augue. Cras condimentum, orci non vehicula rutrum, purus diam fermentum est, ut pretium urna risus a mauris. Aliquam pretium, nunc quis mattis mattis, felis mauris euismod massa, a elementum massa felis sed metus. Nunc porttitor metus a lorem mollis nec ornare erat placerat. Aenean eget lacus libero. Vivamus hendrerit, ligula eget porta mollis, tortor velit dictum neque, ac sagittis enim quam gravida erat. Aenean eu leo quis erat aliquam volutpat id eget lorem. Integer eleifend mi eget magna dapibus commodo. Fusce id dui vel augue porta hendrerit eu vitae sapien. Nullam tellus nisi, elementum imperdiet vehicula sit amet, egestas in risus. Curabitur nec tortor et est feugiat convallis. Mauris sed rhoncus urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin mattis placerat dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu nibh, adipiscing quis feugiat ut, mattis a velit.}
\begin{document}
A block quotation with the multiple citation --- note that the author name, for example, appears reduced to its surname (even in the first citation):
\blockquote{\loremipsum\autocites(Some global pre-note)(some global post-note)[some local pre-note][100]{test1a}[apud][200]{test2a}\relax}
A first block quotation, with a full citation of \texttt{test1} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][100]{test1}{\loremipsum}
A first block quotation, with a full citation of \texttt{test2} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][100]{test2}{\loremipsum}
A second block quotation, with a shortened citation of \texttt{test1} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][200]{test1}{\loremipsum}
A second block quotation, with a shortened citation of \texttt{test2} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][200]{test2}{\loremipsum}
A block quotation with the multiple citation --- note that the author name, for example, appears reduced to its surname:
\blockquote{\loremipsum\autocites(Some global pre-note)(some global post-note)[some local pre-note][100]{test1}[apud][200]{test2}\relax}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `\blockcquote` indeed accepts only single citations. With regard to your workaround and `\autocite` not respecting the global citation style, please provide a compilable example.

Comment: @lockstep I added a compilable example that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of pasting `\autocites` after the quoted text, use the optional argument of `\blockquote`. Note that if your `\autocites` command also includes optional arguments, you have to wrap it into an additional set of curly braces.

BTW, your minimal example was exemplary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% To add the contents of the .bib file in the .tex file
    \begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
        @book{test1,
            author = {John Doe},
            title = {Example book to be cited},
            address = {Nowhere},
            publisher = {Some Publisher},
            year = {1990},
        }
        @book{test2,
            author = {Jane Smith},
            title = {A book that cites the former},
            address = {Somewhere},
            publisher = {A Publishing House},
            year = {2010},
        }
    \end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
    \SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
    \SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}
    \renewcommand*{\mkcitation}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\loremipsum}{%  I did this because using the lipsum package, the reference appeared in a new line
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus ante at urna tempor iaculis. Donec et mi augue. Cras condimentum, orci non vehicula rutrum, purus diam fermentum est, ut pretium urna risus a mauris. Aliquam pretium, nunc quis mattis mattis, felis mauris euismod massa, a elementum massa felis sed metus. Nunc porttitor metus a lorem mollis nec ornare erat placerat. Aenean eget lacus libero. Vivamus hendrerit, ligula eget porta mollis, tortor velit dictum neque, ac sagittis enim quam gravida erat. Aenean eu leo quis erat aliquam volutpat id eget lorem. Integer eleifend mi eget magna dapibus commodo. Fusce id dui vel augue porta hendrerit eu vitae sapien. Nullam tellus nisi, elementum imperdiet vehicula sit amet, egestas in risus. Curabitur nec tortor et est feugiat convallis. Mauris sed rhoncus urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin mattis placerat dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu nibh, adipiscing quis feugiat ut, mattis a velit.}
\begin{document}
A block quotation with the multiple citation --- now the first citation also shows prenames:
\blockquote[{\autocites(Some global pre-note)(some global post-note)[some local pre-note][100]{test1}[apud][200]{test2}}][]{\loremipsum}
A first block quotation, with a full citation of \texttt{test1} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][100]{test1}{\loremipsum}
A first block quotation, with a full citation of \texttt{test2} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][100]{test2}{\loremipsum}
A second block quotation, with a shortened citation of \texttt{test1} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][200]{test1}{\loremipsum}
A second block quotation, with a shortened citation of \texttt{test2} ref.:
\blockcquote[some pre-note][200]{test2}{\loremipsum}
A block quotation with the multiple citation --- note that the author name, for example, appears reduced to its surname:
\blockquote[{\autocites(Some global pre-note)(some global post-note)[some local pre-note][100]{test1}[apud][200]{test2}}][]{\loremipsum}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Added `\renewcommand*{\mkcitation}[1]{#1}` and (just to be sure) added empty second optional argument to `\blockquote`.

Comment: There's one issue I hadn't noted before, because I just looked at the footnote, and not to its mark :P... The problem is: the footnote mark of the citation within the `\blockquote` optional argument appears between parenteses: e.g. (²). I tried to use both `\footcites` and `\smartcites` this way, but the problem persisted...

Comment: @henrique: Dang. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: It worked perfectly now, even without the second optional argument to `\blockquote`! thanks!