# csquotes and nested citations

Tags: biblatex, citing, nesting, csquotes

It looks like the `csquotes` package does not allow nested citations such as

```
\foreignblockcquote{foreign language}[pre-note]
  [post-note with citation \textcite{key2}]
  {key1}[punctuation]{quoted text}
```

The error message is

```
Package biblatex error: nested citation command. See the biblatex package document for explanation
```

but I could not find anything in the `csquotes` and `biblatex` user guides. Originally, I was interested in using the `\textcite` command developed by Audrey in
[biblatex footcite and footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50219/biblatex-footcite-and-footnote)

This question may also be related to
[Is it possible to make automatic multiple citations with csquotes and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19823/is-it-possible-to-make-automatic-multiple-citations-with-csquotes-and-biblatex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with `csquotes` -- `biblatex` does not allow nested citations. In your case, I'd use `\foreignblockquote` (without the "c") and the `\cites` "Qualified citation list" command (see section 3.7.3 of the `biblatex` manual). (Note that because I use `\cites`' optional argument, I have to wrap the command into additional braces in the optional argument of `\foreignblockquote`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\foreignblockcquote{ngerman}{A01}{\blindtext}

\foreignblockquote{ngerman}[{\cites{A01}[see also][]{B02}}]{\blindtext}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]