# As quoted by a certain author

Tags: citing, quoting

Is it possible to add "as quoted by" in the `\parencite` command?

I have a body of text as a quotation by author 1 and in it there is another quotation by author 2.

I tried `\parencite[as quoted by author1][200]{author2}`. But I don't get the right output, namely *author2 as quoted by author 1*.

I guess the only solution is the use the `\cite` command?

(`\cite[][200]{author2}` as quoted by `\citeauthor{author1}`)

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`? Please advise.

Comment: Nested citations are not allowed in BibLaTeX. You may want to have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53891/csquotes-and-nested-citations/53923#53923) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/biblatex-nested-citations-with-the-textcites-command) for possible solutions.